# React testing library hover event

Tags: reactjs, hover, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a sidebar component. I am using material UI and JSS.
I can't paste all of my code but these are the important parts:

SideBar.tsx

```
...
<a className={classes.item}>
    <span>Icon</span>
    <span className={classes.itemTitle}> 
        Title
    </span>
</a>
...
```

Styles.ts

```
...
itemTitle: {
    display: "none"
},
item: {
    ...
    '&:hover': {
        ...
        '& > $itemTitle': {
             ...
             display: "inline-block"
        }
     }
}
...
```

In short, when hovering above the icon the title should appear.
I tried to test this behavior in react testing library but failed, it's important to note that it does work when I hover above the icon.

I tried doing the following:

1. Printing `screen.debug()`, seems like the title is already there, so I had to use `toBeVisible`
2. Tried mouseOver/mouseEnter/both, but it did not triggered the styles.
3. Tried using hover from userEvent but got the same result.
4. I read somewhere that RTL does not recalculate CSS, so I tried using `getComputedStyle`, but the display property was none.

Any ideas on how to test this case?